# Syslog-NG conditional routing

Tags: linux, syslog-ng

I have the following configuration.  I'm totally new to Syslog-NG, so help is appreciated.

```
@version: 3.30
@include "scl.conf"

options 
{
    flush_lines (0);
    time_reopen (10);
    log_fifo_size (1000);
    chain_hostnames (off);
    use_dns (yes);
    use_fqdn (yes);
    create_dirs (yes);
    keep_hostname (yes);
    normalize_hostnames (yes);
    stats_freq (600);
    stats_level (2);
};

source s_local 
{
  internal();
};

source s_network 
{
  syslog(transport(udp) port(5514));
};

destination d_logs 
{
    file
    (
      "/var/log/all_logs.log"
      create_dirs(yes)
    );
};
  
log {source(s_network); destination(d_logs);};
```

I'm hoping there is a way that I can route each program type into it's own file (e.g.. dpinger.log, sshd.log, unbound.log, etc..) without having to explicitly define them in advance OR if I'm able to provide a list of programs to break out and then have the rest dump into a default file that would actually be EVEN BETTER.

I'm definitely pouring through the Syslog-NG documentation, but I'm so new to it that I don't really know what to look for at this point, so I thought to seek some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@version: 3.30
@include "scl.conf"

options 
{
    flush_lines (0);
    time_reopen (10);
    log_fifo_size (1000);
    chain_hostnames (off);
    use_dns (yes);
    use_fqdn (yes);
    create_dirs (yes);
    keep_hostname (yes);
    normalize_hostnames (yes);
    stats_freq (600);
    stats_level (2);
};

source s_local 
{
  internal();
};

source s_network 
{
  syslog(transport(udp) port(5514));
};

filter f_whitelist { in-list("/config/program.list", value("PROGRAM")); };
filter f_blacklist { not in-list("/config/program.list", value("PROGRAM")); };

destination d_split_logs 
{
    file
    (
      "/config/log/$PROGRAM.log"
      create_dirs(yes)
    );
};

destination d_logs 
{
    file
    (
      "/config/log/syslog"
      create_dirs(yes)
    );
};
  
log 
{
  source(s_local );
  source(s_network);

  filter(f_whitelist);
  destination(d_split_logs);
  log 
  {
    source(s_local );
    source(s_network);
    filter(f_blacklist);
    destination(d_logs);
  };
};
```

Comment: This seems to work so far...